# Block updating .NET Framework

Tags: .net, windows-update

For compatibility reasons I want to keep the current .NET Framework version (which is 4.7, the latest version) and stop automatic/silent updates in the future from Windows Update or WSUS only for .NET Framework version while allowing all other system/security updates on a Windows Server 2008 or 2012.
I have found answers for how to prevent updating to a certain .NET Framework version or how to hide the update from the list of updates in Windows Update after the update is already available, but this is not what I want.
What I'm interested is preventing updating from a .NET Framework version when we don't know if, when and to what version an upgrade will be available. E.g. the latest .NET Framework available is version 4.7. Future versions could be 4.7.1, 4.7.2, 4.8 or 4.9 but we don't know yet. How can one prevent these future updates from being installed by Windows Update or WSUS on a Windows Server 2008/2012?

Comment: Only one hour passed since I have asked my question and already have a negative vote which means that my question "does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful" :D
Following quote from my question shows (some) research effort: "I have found answers for how to prevent updating to a certain .NET Framework version or how to hide the update from the list of updates in Windows Update after the update is already available, but this is not what I want."

Comment: This quote shows the usefulness: "For compatibility reasons I want to keep the current .NET Framework version (which is 4.7, the latest version) and stop automatic/silent updates in the future from Windows Update or WSUS only for .NET Framework version while allowing all other system/security updates on a Windows Server 2008 or 2012".
If there is something unclear please ask for clarification in a comment.

Comment: I suspect the downvotes are because what you are trying to do would negatively impact any other code which needs to run on a computer you did this to. If your code needs 4.7 and my code needs some hypothetical 4.8, then you blocking updates would prevent my code from ever running. That's unacceptable developer behavior. Thankfully it's unnecessary; see my answer below.

Comment: @Necoras: That is why we would only run code that needs 4.7 on that specific computer. For code that would need some hypothetical 4.8 we would setup a new machine just for that. And it is necessary, see my comment on your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is a very sensible question, and I'm a bit surprised that the whole internet seems to be trusting Microsoft not to break their stuff (at least in the context of automatic web server .NET Runtime updates).

Yes, what you are asking is [not recommended by Microsoft](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4342394/how-to-temporarily-block-the-installation-of-net-framework-4-7-2).

> **Important** We strongly recommend that you do not block the installation
>   of .NET Framework 4.7.2. However, you may have a business reason to
>   temporarily block the installation. For example, you may require more
>   time to test line-of-business applications in your environment. In
>   such a case, you can modify the registry to temporarily block this
>   installation.

And yes, Microsoft .NET Framework Windows Updates are intended to be fully backwards compatible.

But for a critical application on a Production server, there is a definite risk to automatically rolling out version upgrades to the underlying code without first testing them in a Staging environment.  Although rare, there are [known instances](https://blog.sentry.io/2018/05/14/windows-10-update-might-have-broken-your-dotnet-app) of existing applications being broken by Microsoft's in-place Windows Updates.  (This is also a risk for updates generally, including [security updates](https://redmondmag.com/articles/2018/07/23/microsoft-pulls-july-net-patches.aspx).)

**To answer your question:**

No, there does not appear to be any server-level setting that allows you to block future, unannounced .NET Framework updates generally for computers that directly connect to Windows Update.

As an alternative, the following three workarounds could help you to prevent an untested .NET Runtime update:

1. If your organization uses an update management solution, such as Microsoft WSUS or System Center Configuration Manager, those tools can be used to selectively approve or defer your updates individually.
2. You could always stay one version behind.  (Ex: Don't update to .NET 4.7.2 until you can confirm the next "BlockNetFramework48" setting name.)
3. (Less reliable) Recent .NET Framework version updates have been rolled out as Recommended updates.  If you disable Recommended updates that might partially mitigate the risk that a future .NET Framework version update would be rolled out automatically without testing.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to. You can [install and run multiple versions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/how-to-determine-which-versions-are-installed) of the .Net Framework concurrently. Your application can then target a specific version. So long as that version is available, it doesn't matter what newer versions are also available.

Comment: You can install and run multiple .NET Framework versions only if those versions are say 3.5 and 4.6.2, but not if those versions are 4.0 and 4.7 or any other 4.x version in between. All 4.x versions are installed in the same folder, on top of the previous version so only the newest installed version is available.